# How to fetch data from multi dimensional array in react native from api of php?

Tags: reactjs, native

data :

```
[ 
  { "flat": 
    [ 
      { 
        "title": "flat", 
        "quote": { 
          "flat": { 
            "code": "flat.flat", 
            "title": "flat", 
            "cost": "5.00", 
            "tax_class_id": "9", 
            "text": "5.00" 
          } 
        }, 
        "sort_order": "1", 
        "error": false 
      } 
    ] 
  }, 
  { "pickup": 
    [ 
      { 
        "title": "pickup", 
        "quote": { 
          "pickup": { 
            "code": "pickup.pickup",
            "title": "pickup", 
            "cost": 0, 
            "tax_class_id": 0, 
            "text": 0 
          } 
        }, 
        "sort_order": "3", 
        "error": false 
      } 
    ] 
  }, 
  { "free": 
  [ 
    { 
      "title": "free",
      "quote": { 
        "free": { 
          "code": "free.free", 
          "title": "free", 
          "cost": 0, 
          "tax_class_id": 0, 
          "text": 0 
        } 
      }, 
      "sort_order": "0", 
      "error": false 
    } 
  ] 
}, { 
  "auspost": [ 
    { 
      "title": "auspost", 
      "quote": { 
        "Courier": { 
          "code": "auspost.Courier", 
          "title": "Courier", 
          "cost": "246.65", 
          "tax_class_id": "9", 
          "text": "246.65" 
        }, 
        "Express": { 
          "code": "auspost.Express", 
          "title": "Express", 
          "cost": "196.65", 
          "tax_class_id": "9", 
          "text": "196.65"
         }, 
         "Standard": { 
           "code": "auspost.Standard", 
           "title": "Standard", 
           "cost": "185.65", 
           "tax_class_id": "9", 
           "text": "185.65" 
          } 
        }, 
        "sort_order": "0", 
        "error": "" 
      } 
    ] 
  } 
]
```

Comment: What have you attempted? What is the error you are getting? Please post a snippet of the code that you have and the error log if any.

Comment: Use AXIOS (https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/).

Comment: [{"flat": {"title": "flat","quote": {"flat": {"code": "flat.flat","title": "flat","cost": "5.00","tax_class_id": "9","text": "5.00"} },"sort_order": "1","error": false}},{
        "pickup": {
            "title": "pickup",
            "quote": {
                "pickup": {
                    "code": "pickup.pickup",
                    "title": "pickup",
                    "cost": 0,
                    "tax_class_id": 0,
                    "text": 0
                }
            },
            "sort_order": "3",
            "error": false
        }
    }

Comment: i have to fetch this two array in react native

Answer (score 0):

Use axios for any API calls,

Reference: https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/